# Competing consumers on Apache Camel RabbitMQ endpoint

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

[image]

I have four exact replicas of a service that *among other things* catch messages from a certain queue using Apache Camel RabbitMQ endpoints. Each route looks like this:

```
//Start Process from RabbitMQ queue
    from("rabbitmq://" +
            System.getenv("ADVERTISE_ADDRESS") +
            "/" +
            System.getenv("RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME") +
            "?routingKey=" +
            System.getenv("RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY") +
            "&autoAck=true")
            .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody()))
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, TwitterBean.class)
            .transform().method(ResponseTransformer.class, "transformtwitterBean")
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            .to("http4://" + System.getenv("ADVERTISE_ADDRESS") + ":" + System.getenv("CAMUNDA_PORT") + "/rest/process-definition/key/MainProcess/start")
            .log("Response: ${body}");
```

Right now each endpoint processes the message. 
Even though the "concurrent consumers"-option by default is one.
I assumed that maybe my messages weren't acknowledged,
so I set the autoAck option to true.

This didn't help, how can I make these services competing consumers?

EDIT:

A code snippet from the configuration of my publisher app:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig {
    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME"), true);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME"), true, true);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY"));
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: `process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody()))` Wouldn't this just set the in body to the value already present?

Comment: @Novaterata, quite possible. I haven't worked with Camel for 1.5+ now so I'm unable to clear that up for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you're not naming your queue on the service side

Based on the [camel apache rabbitmq documentation](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html), this means that a random name is generated for the queue.

So:

- you have a publisher that sends a message to an **exchange**
- then each of your service creates a **queue** with a random name, and *binds* it to the exchange

Each service having it's own queue, bound to the same exchange, will get the same messages.

To avoid this you need to provide a queue name, 
so that each service will connect to the same **queue**, which will mean they will share the message consumption with the other service instances.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like **you don't have a Queue, but a Topic**. See [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html) for a comparison.

The message broker is responsible to give **a queue message to only one consumer**, no matter how much of them are present.

Comment: I've added a code snippet for my publisher app config, would you care to take a look? It looks like I've instantiated a queue, but my RabbitMQ knowledge is quite limited.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know RabbitMQ either. Perhaps in RabbitMQ the naming is different too. What you currently have is publish/subscribe. What you want seems to be named "work queue" in RabbitMQ. At least in [this tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html). Hope this helps

Comment: [I use Spring AMQP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-spring-amqp.html) and it seems that you have to declare all listening consumers in the publisher app. Unfortunately I can't do this since consumers are being auto-scaled by Docker Swarm Mode...